# Cant install KB 980368 "The update is not applicable to your computer"

Tags: windows-server-2008, xeon, knowledge-base

I'm trying to install [KB 980368](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/980368) *A update is available that enables certain IIS 7.0 or IIS 7.5 handlers to handle requests whose URLs do not end with a period* on a new Windows 2008 R2 server, but no matter which of the download packages I try, they all say "The update is not applicable to your computer"

I have Windows 2008 R2 Standard on an Intel Xeon E5520.  I need that KB to have extenstionless URLs in ASP.NET MVC2.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Note, you don't need this for extension-less URLs unless you are matching with `*.`.

Comment: Anyone know if this same error comes up on a VMWare installation specifically? I have Server 2008 R2 SP1 installed already and still get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you apply SP1 to your R2 installation?  If so, then you don't need to install that KB